# Uploading shapefile to Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have tried to upload a shapefile to GEE using only the extensions .shx .shp .sbn .dbf and .cpg and I keep getting the following error:

> Error: Unable to transform edge (258573.666225, -3764973.048903 to
> 258573.666230, -3764973.048914) from EPSG:4326 PLANAR to EPSG:4326.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I think this tutorial is a good reference for you to review [Uploading a shapefile to Google Earth Engine](https://thegeoict.com/blog/2019/08/05/uploading-a-shapefile-to-google-earth-engine/). Here are the details below to the steps you can take that can solve your issue.

1. In Code Editor, shapefiles can be uploaded to the assets. In the code editor, on the left side panel, go to Assets.
2. Click NEW and Table upload.shape-file-upload
   [image: Uploading a shapefile to table]
3. In the popup screen. Make sure you have the correct path for the asset. Click SELECT. Point to the directory that has your shapefile. Earth Engine takes these extensions to be valid shapefile.
   a) .dbf
   b) .shx
   c) .cpg
   d) .fix
   e) .qix
   f) .sbn
   g) .prj
   h) .shp
   i) .shp.xml
   Note: the .sbx and .qpj file is not considered valid.vbj5ljg
4. Click OK and let it finish upload the shapefile. You can check the status of the file upload on the Tasks tab on the right-side panel on the GEE playground.
   Once it finishes uploading, on the code editor, locate your assets. It will be the same name that was given while uploading.mxz7qyn
5. Click on the import icon. Now on the editor, you will see it as named default.  You can rename it as you want. Use .geometry() function to get the geometry of the uploaded table.